# Correlation equivalent to find trend within one variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to find the trend of a variable or a feature over a period of time. 
That is no of sales done by a sales representative over a period of time.

**Lets say:**

```
Year     No.of.sales
2012          10
2013          12
2014          16
2015          18
```

Looking at this figures, I can say that, the performance of the sales representative is gradually increasing over the period. And, the no of sales are decreasing, then the performance is decreasing and so.on,.

I wanted a statistical method to find the trend within the single variables.

If I have two variables, then I would have seen Correlation. But, I need to see the trend of the sales. What is the **statistical technique** I can use, which gives me a **standardized value**.

Comment: It sounds like you want to fit a trendline. This is a standard function is for example excel. Are you interested in the math behind it or in programming such a function yourself?

Comment: Math behind it as well as the programming if possible

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do have 2 different variables. Namely the year and the sales result. What you could do is regression to predict the values for years in the future. An example to do this in R can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15102307/3426322
In his code example replace X by the years and Y by the sales result. Then use for linear regression:

```
fit <- glm(y~x)
co <- coef(fit)
```

And for fitting various non-linear functions use:

```
f <- function(x,a,b,d) {(a*x^2) + (b*x) + d}  
fit <- nls(y ~ f(x,a,b,d), start = c(a=1, b=1, d=1))   
co <- coef(fit)
```

This examples fits a quadratic curve, but you can adapt f as desired. Similar functions are available in various languages.

Comment: I have only 4 data points, 2013,2014,2015,2016 only. Out of this I have to find the performance of the sales representative .